# creative puzzle how to animate brids eye view wave ripples

Tags: javascript, css-animations

so i have these two divs (the water and the continent) and I would like to have a subtle wave animation so that at the shoreline of the us landmass small waves would emanate and spread outward.

Javascript? Canvas? Mootools? Jquery? I would just appreciate people brainstorming or offering resources and/or examples that I coud look at.

[image]

Comment: CreateJS : http://www.createjs.com and Three.js : http://threejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

found this amazing demo : )

http://29a.ch/2010/10/23/html5-water-ripples-demo

heres another

http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/effects/water/00/

Javascript and Canvas are both important for realistic and pragmatic clientside animations, some browsers are better at handling these animations than others of course (chrome). As to Mootools, or jQuery, they are both just libraries - you may choose which is best for you, but jQuery is the most popular. i was surprised to see how short the first demos source code was.

Comment: thanks! I am going to leave the question unanswered for now so that others might chime in, but ill come back around and greencheck yours

Comment: you da man will delphia. to be honest, forgot i even left these comments. just had too much fun making ripples again. thats what its all about